# How to prove Lemma 1.6 in the book "Reinforcement Learning: Theory and Algorithms"

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, markov-decision-process, proofs

I am trying to prove the following lemma from [Reinforcement Learning: Theory and Algorithms](https://rltheorybook.github.io/rltheorybook_AJKS.pdf) on page 8.

Lemma 1.6. We have that:
$$
\left[(1-\gamma)\left(I-\gamma P^{\pi}\right)^{-1}\right]_{(s, a),\left(s^{\prime}, a^{\prime}\right)}=(1-\gamma)\sum_{h=0}^{\infty} \gamma^{t} \mathbb{P}_{h}^{\pi}\left(s_{h}=s^{\prime}, a_{h}=a^{\prime} \mid s_{0}=s, a_{0}=a\right)
$$
where $\pi$ is a deterministic and stationary policy with:
$$
P_{(s, a),\left(s^{\prime}, a^{\prime}\right)}^{\pi}:=\left\{\begin{aligned}
P\left(s^{\prime} \mid s, a\right) & \text { if } a^{\prime}=\pi\left(s^{\prime}\right) \\
0 & \text { if } a^{\prime} \neq \pi\left(s^{\prime}\right)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
The Corollary 1.5 should also be useful: $Q^{\pi}=\left(I-\gamma P^{\pi}\right)^{-1} r$

To be honest, I don't have much idea to do it. I saw that the LHS of Lemma 1.6 is related to $Q^\pi$, so my idea is to expand Q and see if it's possible to separate out the $r$. I did the following but end up clueless,
$$\begin{aligned}
Q^{\pi}(s, a) &=E\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^{t} R\left(s_{t}, a_{t}\right) \mid \pi, s_{0}=s, a_{0}=a\right] \\
\
&=R(s, a)+\gamma \sum_{s^{\prime}} P\left(s^{\prime} \mid s, a\right) E\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^{t} R\left(s_{t+1} \cdot a_{t+1}\right) \mid \pi, S_{1}=s^{\prime}, a_{1}=\pi\left(s^{\prime}\right)=a^{\prime}\right] \\ &= R(s, a)+\gamma \sum_{s^{\prime}} P\left(s^{\prime} \mid s, a\right) \left[R(s^\prime,a^\prime) + \gamma\sum_{s^{\prime\prime}}P(s^{\prime\prime}|s^\prime,a^\prime)Q(s^{\prime\prime}, a^{\prime\prime})\right]
\end{aligned}$$
I have been staring at this equation for hours with no progress. I hope I can get some guidance from you guys.